# How to stop user entering date in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datepicker

I am trying to stop user from entering back date than the first one and i am unable to do that

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#date_rash_onset").datepicker({
    todayBtn: 1,
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
  }).on('changeDate', function(selected) {
    var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    $('#date_investigation').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
    $('#date_collection').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
  });

  $("#date_investigation").datepicker({
      format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
  }).on('changeDate', function(selected) {
    var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    $('#date_rash_onset').datepicker('setEndDate', minDate);
    $('#date_date_onset').datepicker('endDate', '+0d');
  });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just disable it after date is set? `$("#date_rash_onset").datepicker('disable');`

Comment: i want that when user selected 06/03/2017 as date_rash_onset then he will be unable to select 05/03/2017 as date_collection

Comment: You want to specify date range with two datepickers? in that case there are planty of libraries and examples
https://github.com/longbill/jquery-date-range-picker , 
http://jsfiddle.net/c0mm0n/SJhmF/3/

Comment: can you explain a bit you problem?.

Answer (score 0):

```
function fromDate(start_date_id, end_date_id){
       var from_date = $('#'+start_date_id).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy' }).val();
    var to_date = $("#"+end_date_id).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy' }).val();
    $("#"+end_date_id).datepicker('setStartDate', from_date);
    $("#"+end_date_id).datepicker('setEndDate', '+2y');
    if(to_date < from_date){
      $("#"+end_date_id).val('');
    }
  }

  function toDate(start_date_id, end_date_id){
    $('#'+start_date_id).datepicker('setStartDate', "01-01-1925");
    $('#'+start_date_id).datepicker('setEndDate', '+0d');
  }
  $("#date_rash_onset").on( "change", function() {
        fromDate('date_rash_onset', 'date_collection');
      });


    $("#date_collection").on( "change", function() {
        toDate('date_rash_onset', 'date_collection');
      });
```